# Google Adwords Campaign vs Googe Analytics

Tags: analytics, google-ads-api

I currently one adwords account and one analytics account. In each account I manage two sites. So I have multiple adword campaigns for one site, and same for the other site. When looking at data in the analytics campaign all campaigns are linked to one site. How do I assign one campaign to one site and another campaign to another site in analytics?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are to ways to fix this:

1. You could filter your Analytics Account. So for example one campaign in AdWords is called "Page-A" and the other "Page-B" - open in GA Admin > Select the Property and View > Filters > "Add Filter" and now exclude the campaign "Page-A" from the "Page-B" Analytics-Account.
2. Turn off the Auto-Tagging in AdWords and put your own URL-Parameters to your Final URLs

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer, but how to find the View->Filters->Add Filter in GA?